# Why are the metal tubes of Mechazilla base thinner than the tubes of its claw?

Tags: spacex, spacex-starship, spacex-super-heavy

[image]

From [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-ThNeIGtBY) and other sources. You can see that the lines at the left ("claw") are thicker than lines ar right ("base.")

Why? Intuitively, it seems that it should be the opposite.

Comment: Because that's how structural engineering works Members that must withstand longitudinal forces can always be thinner and lighter than members that must withstand transverse, and especially torsional forces.

Answer (score 2):

Why should it intuitively be opposite?

They carry out different functions. The base is a very rigid structure with 3 attachment points to the OLIT, and is only subject to tension - so is very strong by its very nature.

The claw does not have that inherent strength - it has one pivot point and the free end is unsupported, so it has torsion (twisting) as well as potentially compression and tension.

Comment: The pivot point is even more strange for me :)